# Streamwriter.Writeline and File.WriteAllText writing text out of order

Tags: c#, xml, filestream

I'm having an issue where I'm writing the contents of several xml files to one file. When I run the program, the output is in the proper format, but the words are out of order. An example of this:

My string is `"<s:AttributeType name=\"Shift\" number=\"34\" nullable=\"true\" writeunknown=\"true\">"`

So it should print `<s:AttributeType name="Shift" number="34" nullable="true" writeunknown="true">`

But instead `<s:AttributeType name="Shift" writeunknown="true" number="34" nullable="true">`

is returned.

Some of the file is written in using `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\status.xml", xsh);`
Where 'xsh' is a variable containing a string.

The rest is written in using this loop:

```
 foreach (var i in Numbers.GetWSnumber())
        {
            string contents = "";
            string curFile = @"\\production\public\Staus\TStatus\WS" + i.SetId + ".xml";
            if (File.Exists(curFile))
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(curFile);
                while ((contents = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\status.xml"))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(contents);
                    }   


                }
                file.Close();
            }
        }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Semantically, there's no difference when xml attributes are reordered. Why is this a problem?

Comment: You are aware that the actual and the expected output are semantically the same, as the order of attributes is irrelevant in Xml, right?

Comment: It sounds to me like an XML parser is involved at some point.

Comment: Just added the code. @spender I did not know if it would make a difference or not, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @spender True, but that doesn't answer his question at all -- which I think is to find out why this is happening. If it writes the properties in the same out-of-order order then it might be okay, but if its different every time it would impact the readability of whatever he's outputting to.

Comment: It is very unlikely that the current sample code will reorder XML attributes. What it likely to cause is creation of invalid XML as result (i.e. if happen to merge XML with different encoding or forget open/close tags). As @Cyborgx37 points out most likely reason of the behavior is XML parsing/generation happens and attributes ordered arbitrary by design, not merging files.

Comment: What are you using to check the results of the text file? Is it possible that the editor you are using to view it is reording the attributes (and that they are actually in the correct order)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of XML attributes is not important so I wouldn't worry about it. However, if it's really bugging you I would suggest moving your using statement.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\status.xml"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(contents);
}
```

Although this is probably optimized so that it works the same as if it were better written, the way you currently have this a new `StreamWriter` is being allocated and then disposed of with every iteration.

Your using statement should wrap the `while` loop and not the other way around. This could possibly solve the problem (though I think it's unlikely) as I don't know how the compiler is handling this line. Either way, it's worth changing.

Comment: I don't think changing the position of the `using` block is going to have any effect, although you are right that it would be much more efficient to do so.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Yeah I don't think that it would either, but if you're not using an XML reader/writer I have no idea how the string could change. The answer is more of a general suggestion to improve the code than a solution to the specific problem.